# SQL Datediff with group by

Tags: sql, group-by, datediff

I have a table called Login. I want to get the No. of days from the last login per user
See sample data below:

```
tableName: Login    
ID|UserName|LoginDateTime  
1 |User1   |04/09/12 18:07:06  
2 |User1   |04/09/12 18:07:51  
3 |User1   |04/09/12 18:21:41  
4 |Admin   |17/09/12 15:36:30  
5 |Admin   |17/09/12 15:36:30
```

Here is my SQL command:

```
SELECT LoginDateTime, UserName,(DATEDIFF (DAY, [LoginDateTime], GETDATE ())) 
AS [datediff] 
FROM Login;
```

Result:

```
ID|UserName|LoginDateTime    |No. of Days  
1 |User1   |04/09/12 18:07:06|414  
2 |User1   |04/09/12 18:07:51|414  
3 |User1   |04/09/12 18:21:41|414  
4 |Admin   |17/09/12 15:36:30|401  
5 |Admin   |17/09/12 15:36:30|401
```

But I want to remove the duplicate records

```
ID|UserName|LoginDateTime    |No. of Days   
1 |User1   |04/09/12 18:07:06|414  
2 |Admin   |17/09/12 15:36:30|401
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, if you want to get the latest login for each user.

```
SELECT UserName, MAX([LoginDateTime]) AS LoginDateTime,
   (DATEDIFF (DAY, MAX([LoginDateTime]), GETDATE ())) as [datediff]
FROM Login
GROUP BY UserName
```

The idea is to use `GROUP BY` to group all your rows by Username, and Using `MAX` aggregate function get only the row with the latest LoginDateTime, then calculate the number of days using that latest loginDateTime.

Comment: thanks for the reply but I got an error "invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: I updated the answer some minutes ago, check I added MAX to the loginDateTime within datediff function

Comment: Strange, the ID is in the GROUP BY, that was not causing any issue.

Comment: @Anjali, yes probably, I tried to explain a bit more the answer.

Comment: @Anjali, show your evidence if the query works fine if you include field ID